# React 'Module Not Found' when running Nextjs Website

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, dependencies

I am migrating an existing react app to Nextjs to improve the routing and take advantage of some of the features. I am running into an error that I cannot troubleshoot. [image: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDme6.png)]

I installed the dependencies of the original application using
`npm install`. And after migrating the dependencies in the package.json.
When I run
`npm list react`
I receive all of these dependency errors. Nextjs requires react ^18.2.0 currently.
[npm list react error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7qM9.png)
Is there something wrong with the versioning of these peer dependencies and using the current version of react? Is there a simple way to troubleshoot this other than rewriting the code to use different packages?
React is specified as ^18.2.0 in the dependencies in the package.json.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your `package.json` and add  `react ^18.2.0`  to the `dependencies` list and run `npm i` again. You'll need to delete the `package-lock.json` file first.

Or just run:

```
npm i react react-dom @types/react @types/react-dom
```

You can Try to delete your package-lock file and `run rm -rf node_modules`, `npm cache clean --force`, and then run `npm i` again. Hope it helps!

Comment: I deleted the package-lock.json and react is given ^18.2.0 in the package.json. I ran the snippet you gave and I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: You use npm, right? Try to delete your package-lock file and run `rm -rf node_modules`, `npm cache clean --force` and then run `npm i` again

Comment: That seemed to work after deleting some conflicting dependencies! Thank you!